# Evaluating limits of a function on $\mathbb R^2$ without epsilon-delta

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm trying to justify that all the limits below are zero (without directly using epsilon-delta).

1. $\lim_{(x,y)\to (1,2)} \frac{(x-1)^2}{\sqrt{(x-1)^2+(y-2)^2}}$

For this one, is it okay to say that $\frac{a^2}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\leq \frac{a^2+b^2}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$, and then use that $A\leq B$ implies $\lim A \leq \lim B$?

2. $\lim_{(x,y)\to (1,2)} \frac{(x-1)^4}{\sqrt{(x-1)^2+(y-2)^2}}$

Here, I'm tempted to say that $a^4/\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\leq a^2/\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ "for $a$ close to zero" and then use the above. But I'm not entirely satisfied with this argument -- unlike the argument above, this argument isn't very precise because it refers to values "close to zero". Is the only way to make it more precise to use epsilon-delta?

3. $\lim_{(x,y)\to (1,2)} \frac{x-1}{\sqrt{(x-1)^2+(y)^2}}$

This is in a sense the opposite of 2 above. Now it's not true that $a/\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\leq a^2/\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ "for $a$ close to zero". How to handle this case then?

Comment: In the third limit, shouldn't you have $(y-2)^2$ in the denominator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, that's fine.
2. That's fine too, since $|x-1|<1\implies|x-1|^4\leqslant|x-1|^2$.
3. If $x=1+t$, with $t>0$, and $y=2$, then that quotient is $1$. And if $x=1$ and $y\in\Bbb R$, then that quotient is $0$. Therefore, the limit does not exist.